# For whom or For whomever

Tags: difference

I read this sentence from a students essay. I think it sounds odd and think that **whomever** is better. Is this sentence alright?

> What about to buy a dish for (**whom/whomever**) you like?

Comment: I depends what you want to say. ***Whom*** has the feeling that you have a specific person in mind already, ***whomever*** could be anyone.

Answer (score 1):

They mean different things. **Whom** is more specific, and **whomever** less so.  So:

> What about buying a dish for whom you like?

implies that there is *one* person you like, and the question is about buying a dish for that one person. If there were more than one person you like, you would phrase the question as follows:

> What about buying a dish for those whom you like?

But *whomever you like* means, roughly, *It doesn't matter whom*.

> Buy a dish for whomever you like

means: it doesn't really matter whom you buy a dish for; just buy it for one or more people.

> What about buying a dish for whomever we like?

means: *How if we just buy a dish, and it doesn't matter who the intended recipient is?*

Note that in all cases, the verb form is *buying*. *What about to buy* would sound wrong to native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

I've reworded your sentence so it makes sense:

> *What about buying a dish for (whom/whomever) you like?*

This is called a **free choice fused relative construction** where *whom* and *whomever* have the same meaning, though the *ever* is omissible by virtue of being redundant. It's called 'free choice' because it is very similar in meaning to "...*buying a dish for anyone you like*.

It's interpreted as if it had a clausal complement, as in ... "buying a dish for whom(ever) you want to buy a dish for".  So the meaning is not "buying a dish for the persons that you like", but "*buying a dish for **whom(ever) you care to buy one for**".*